# css problems with ul list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to get the last li in my ul list not to show a border.  I do want the borders in between everything else.  I just want small lines as dividers in between my list.  Here is my code:

CSS

```
 #navcontainer ul li { 
        display: inline; 
        border-right:1px solid #5C5C5C;
        margin-left: -12px;
    }
    #navcontainer ul .last li{ 
        display: inline; 
        border-right:0;
        margin-left: -12px;
    }

    #navcontainer ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: .2em 1em;
        color: #5C5C5C;
    }
```

html

```
<ul class="qa-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#rewards" title="Rewards">Rewards Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#logging" title="Logging In">Logging In Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#uploading" title="Uploading Photo">Uploading Photo Questions</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#enter" title="Entering Supporter Email">Entering Supporter Email Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#fb" title="Sharing on Facebook">Sharing on Facebook Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#letter" title="Printing Donation Letter">Printing Donation Letter Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tracking" title="Tracking Donations">Tracking Donations Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#privacy" title="Privacy">Privacy Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#gift" title="Supporter "Thank You" Gift">Supporter "Thank You" Gift Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#rog" title="About Reaching Our Goal">About Reaching Our Goal Questions</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#contact" title="Contact Information Questions">Contact Information Questions</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this for the .last:

```
border-right: none;
```

Also, it doesn't look like you have the `.last` class applied to any of the `li` elements. Additionally, if you do apply it, you'll need to change your selector so that it reads `li.last`, rather than `.last li`.

CSS:

```
#navcontainer ul li.last
{
   ...
   border-right: none;
   ...
}
```

List item:

```
<li class="last">
   <a href="#contact" title="Contact Information Questions">Contact Information Questions</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#navcontainer ul:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: :last-child psuedo-class isn't available in IE < 9

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
#navcontainer ul li:last-child{ 
    display: inline; 
    border-right:none;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

Comment: :last-child psuedo-class isn't available in IE < 9

Comment: IE < 9 stinks, but if you care about supporting the folks using your site, then you have to consider it.

Comment: @TheCrypticNerd - IE8 still shares a generous portion of the browser demographics in general. On top of that, many large corporations use IE7 and IE8 exclusively within their internal network. It's kind of presumptuous to assume OP is not targeting that audience. Thanks for the valuable input though.

Comment: @jaredhoyt Sorry for the comment if it was very embarrassing! (maybe it was :s) My anger gets out of way when that thing comes in front of me. :D AND YES! I know they also keep shares. But if you think about this in a solid way, There is no specification in the question that it should also work on all the browsers include IE < 9. So, I just gave him the easiest and quick solution. If he then asked for cross-browser then I would try to provide the answer in that way! Hope it makes us clear. Thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target it using the CSS3 selector :last-child.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

```
#navcontainer ul li:last-child {
/* CSS here */
}
```